# Puppeteer : Timeout exceeded while waiting for event

Tags: puppeteer

I have an anchor tab with ng-click.

```
<a ng-if="!foo.isDisabled" ng-click="itemTapped($event,foo)" ng-class="getClass(foo)" class="test-class">Test Link</a>
```

I do a broadcast in the `itemTapped` method.

When I click this element from puppeteer script, I am getting this error. `TimeoutError: Timeout exceeded while waiting for event at Timeout.setTimeout (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/helper.js:124:28)`

But as per the screenshot I took after this click event has happened.

`const element = await page.waitForSelector('[class="test-class"]', { visible: true }); await element.click();`

Any pointers on why it is erroring out?